# AWS S3 Access denied from localhost, but working when deployed

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, localhost, aws-sdk

I have NodeJS app that is hosted on ElasticBeanstalk. I have some files on AWS S3 that I need to access.
When app is deployed and accessed from internet I have no problems accessing S3 via AWS SDK. 
However, when I ran app locally on localhost:3000 i get an access denied error.
I made sure the same credentials file is used in both cases.

```
//aws credentials
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
AWS.config.accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID;
AWS.config.secretAccessKey =process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
AWS.config.region = process.env.AWS_S3_REGION;
AWS.config.apiVersions = {"s3": "2006-03-01"};
```

AWS Policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowBucketOnly",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Any suggestions how to resolve it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi.  Can you provide more details on the IAM roles you're using to achieve this please?  Does your ElasticBeanstalk stack use an IAM role?  When you're running the app locally do you also have access to this IAM role?

Comment: Does the S3 bucket have a bucket policy that might deny access? And double-check your credentials are what you think they are.

Comment: @GreenyMcDuff. I have roles defined. I assume that running locally have same access as when running on the web. It looks like I might be wrong. Where can I check the local access?

Comment: @jarmod. My bucket has public access. I am not blocking anything at this point. I checked credentials multiple times.

Comment: Which SDK are you using?  That will make it easier to find out the different methods you can use to specify your credentials

Comment: Oh wait, just saw, you said Node... Give me a sec

Comment: Looking at this (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html), I would suggest you set the following environment variables: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY `.  But you need to make sure the user these credentials are associated with has permission to assume the role your ElasticBeanstalk service uses

Comment: @GreenyMcDuff. I alreadu use AWS credentials. I edited my post to show it

Comment: Can you also show the trust policy associated with the IAM role that your ElasticBeanstalk service uses please?

Comment: @GreenyMcDuff. Added to the post

Comment: Ah, that is the role policy, not the trust policy.  My suspicion is that the IAM role your ElasticBeanstalk service is assuming to access S3 does not trust the entity associated with the credentials you're providing locally.  The only way to be sure of this is to look at the trust policy.  From the IAM console, click on `Roles`, then click on the Role that the policy above is attached to, and then click on `Trust relationships`.  There should be a table with a list of `Trusted entities`, can you pasted what is in there (obfuscate any AWS IDs though)

Comment: @GreenyMcDuff. I am not sure that above policy attached to any Roles. I will have to investigate much more carefully. Thank You for pointing me to the right direction.